# Is there a way to make a delay between 2 word printed in the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, printing, line

```
import time 

x = 1000

while True:

time.sleep(0.05)

x = x - 7

print(x)

if x == 6:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("first", end=" ")
    print("second")
    break
```

I am want to make a delay for like a seconds between two words. I made the count down and at the end to have two wrds being printed in the same line with a delay

Comment: Put the `sleep()` between the prints below and use `flush=True` in the first print. And fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time 

x = 1000

while True:

    time.sleep(0.05)
    x = x - 7
    print(x)

    if x == 6:
        print("first", end=" ", flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("second")
        break
```